# Fix for ScrollRect multi-touch in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

Currently, `ScrollRect` is extremely buggy when it comes to multi-touch on mobile devices.

If you try it out yourself, you will see that whenever you place two fingers on the screen, the content will jump around, and produce some unexpected behaviour.

Are there any solutions to this? Currently, [this](https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/wiki/Controls/MultiTouchScrollRect) is the only solution I have found, but it is still buggy in some cases, and most importantly, does not determine the average input position (or `MultiTouchPosition`) for all your fingers on the screen.

Here is my modified version of the `MultiTouchScrollRect.cs` script from the `UnityUIExtensions` bitbucket, but it jumps every-time I place my next finger on the screen:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MultiTouchScrollRect : ScrollRect
{
    private int minimumTouchCount = 1, maximumTouchCount = 2, pointerId = -100;

    public Vector2 MultiTouchPosition
    {
        get
        {
            Vector2 position = Vector2.zero;
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount && i < maximumTouchCount; i++)
            {
                position += Input.touches[i].position;
            }
            position /= ((Input.touchCount <= maximumTouchCount) ? Input.touchCount : maximumTouchCount);
            return position;
        }
    }

    public override void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >= minimumTouchCount)
        {
            pointerId = eventData.pointerId;
            eventData.position = MultiTouchPosition;
            base.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
        }
    }
    public override void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >= minimumTouchCount)
        {
            eventData.position = MultiTouchPosition;
            if (pointerId == eventData.pointerId)
            {
                base.OnDrag(eventData);
            }
        }
    }
    public override void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >= minimumTouchCount)
        {
            pointerId = -100;
            eventData.position = MultiTouchPosition;
            base.OnEndDrag(eventData);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well if you want the avarage touch position between all touches ... why are you surprised that it jumps to another position when you add a touch? The center between e.g. two points will obviously not be the same as the first point ... So what would you expect to happen?

Comment: @derHugo I’m trying to replicate the iOS photo viewer, and so you can imagine that as you place your second finger down to zoom, it shouldn’t move.

Comment: Then why not simply stick with the first one instead of having an average?

Comment: @derHugo Please try this out for yourself. There is an issue with Unity’s ScrollRect being buggy when you place 2 or more fingers down. I am looking for a way to fix that.

Comment: as I said why not simply only use the first finger for scrolling and ignore the others and use the other ones only for zooming?

Comment: If you look at how the iOS photo viewer works for example, you can place your first finger down, and then, after having scrolled for a bit, you can place your second finger down and zoom in. If you try this out in unity using the default scroll rect, you will find that it cannot handle two or more fingers on the scroll rect, and simply glitch out.

Comment: I don't have iOs so I can't test it ... what I mean is: You are currently implementing your own custom ScrollRect .. so what happens if in that one you simply use only the first touch for scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested, this is the extended ScrollRect class that I wrote which fixes the issue:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace DanielLochner.Assets
{
    public class MultiTouchScrollRect : ScrollRect
    {
        #region Fields
        private int minimumTouchCount = 1, maximumTouchCount = 2, initialTouchCount = 0;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public Vector2 MultiTouchPosition
        {
            get
            {
                Vector2 position = Vector2.zero;
                for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount && i < maximumTouchCount; i++)
                {
                    position += Input.touches[i].position;
                }
                position /= ((Input.touchCount <= maximumTouchCount) ? Input.touchCount : maximumTouchCount);

                return position;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private void Update()
        {
            if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld || UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                {
                    if (initialTouchCount == 0)
                    {
                        initialTouchCount = Input.touchCount;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    initialTouchCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld || UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount >= minimumTouchCount && Input.touchCount == initialTouchCount)
                {
                    eventData.position = MultiTouchPosition;
                    base.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
                }
            }
            else if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop)
            {
                base.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
            }
        }
        public override void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld || UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount >= minimumTouchCount && Input.touchCount == initialTouchCount)
                {
                    eventData.position = MultiTouchPosition;
                    base.OnDrag(eventData);
                }
            }
            else if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop)
            {
                base.OnDrag(eventData);
            }          
        }
        public override void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld || UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount >= minimumTouchCount)
                {
                    eventData.position = MultiTouchPosition;
                    base.OnEndDrag(eventData);
                }
            }
            else if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop)
            {
                base.OnEndDrag(eventData);
            }       
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you efforts Daniel. But the code: UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected will give errors when people build. So I suggest writing like :  #if UNITY_EDITOR
        isRemoteConnected = UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected;
#endif
        if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld || isRemoteConnected)

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative implementation that uses the first touch as the starting point and updates based on the offset of every touch.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace ScrollRect.Extensions
{
    public class MultiTouchScrollRect : ScrollRect
    {
        #region Fields
        private bool _draging = false;
        private Vector2 _dragOffset = Vector2.zero;
        private Dictionary<int, Vector2> _activePointers = new Dictionary<int, Vector2>();
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public bool IsHandheld
        {
            get
            {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                return UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected;
#else
                return SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld;
#endif
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public override void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if (eventData.button != PointerEventData.InputButton.Left)
                return;
            
            if (IsHandheld)
            {
                _activePointers[eventData.pointerId] = eventData.position;
                
                if (Input.touchCount >= 1 && !_draging)
                {
                    base.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
                    _draging = true;
                    _dragOffset = eventData.position;
                }
            }
            else if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop)
            {
                base.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
            }
        }
        public override void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if (eventData.button != PointerEventData.InputButton.Left)
                return;
            
            if (IsHandheld)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount >= 1 && _activePointers.ContainsKey(eventData.pointerId))
                {
                    _dragOffset += eventData.position - _activePointers[eventData.pointerId];
                    _activePointers[eventData.pointerId] = eventData.position;
                    eventData.position = _dragOffset;
                    base.OnDrag(eventData);
                }
            }
            else if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop)
            {
                base.OnDrag(eventData);
            }          
        }
        public override void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if (eventData.button != PointerEventData.InputButton.Left)
                return;
            
            if (IsHandheld)
            {
                if (_activePointers.ContainsKey(eventData.pointerId))
                {
                    _activePointers.Remove(eventData.pointerId);
                }
                
                if (Input.touchCount == 1)
                {
                    base.OnEndDrag(eventData);
                    _draging = false;
                    _dragOffset = Vector2.zero;
                }

            }
            else if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop)
            {
                base.OnEndDrag(eventData);
            }       
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out (haven't tested):

```
public Vector2 MultiTouchPosition
{
    get
    {
        int nTouches = ((Input.touchCount <= maximumTouchCount) ? Input.touchCount : maximumTouchCount);
        if(nTouches == 1)
        {
             return Input.touches[0].position;
        } 
        else 
        {
             return Vector2.Lerp(Input.touches[0].position, Input.touches[1].position, 0.5f); //middle point between them
        }
    }
 }
```

Since the touch amount you want to process can only be one or two, better process each case differently.

I don't know why you tried to divide positions, position is a Vector2 and you need to calculate the middle point between them, it can be done with Vector2.Lerp (0.5f determines you want the middle point)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, however it doesn’t solve the problem. Please do try it yourself when you get back home! I divide by the number of touches, because that ensures I get the average between ALL touches (between $min and $max number of touches), and not just the first and second touches (like it does in your answer).

Comment: Deviding `Vector2` is absolutely no problem. It simply devides all 3 components by the given value => Actually Daniel uses the correct way of getting the avarage of more than two vectors here. However, Daniel, your example strongly suggests that there is maximum touches of 2 so you should either state clearly that it may change or even make it public so you can change it via the Inspector or from the outside instead of hardcoding it.